# Zig "translate c" doesn't translate main function

Tags: c, zig

I created a C file:

```
int main() {
  return 1;
}
```

I used Zig's `translate-c` command line option to generate a zig file, and I only get some global variable declarations like

```
pub const __GCC_ATOMIC_TEST_AND_SET_TRUEVAL = 1;
pub const __FLT16_MAX_EXP__ = 15;
pub const __BIGGEST_ALIGNMENT__ = 16;
pub const __SIZEOF_FLOAT__ = 4;
pub const __INT64_FMTd__ = c"ld";
pub const __STDC_VERSION__ = c_long(201112);
... // and many
```

And no `main` function is found. But if I change the function name to `myFunction` like this:

```
int myFunction(int a) {
  return a;
}
```

A function appears when I re-generate it:

```
pub export fn myFunction(a: c_int) c_int {
    return a;
}
```

Am I missing something? What's the rule of zig's `translate-c` function?

Comment: Did you create the tag `zig`? If so you might want to give it a short desciption in the wiki.

Comment: I don't know about zig. But return 1 seems like the compiler would just replace the function call with 1.

Comment: @KamiKaze Yes I did and the wiki edit is awaiting peer review.

Comment: have you tried replacing the main function with something that is not deterministic at compile time?

Comment: ...e.g. `int main() { int a; scanf("%d", a); return a;`. Now, the compiler cannot forsee/optimize the result of `main()`.

Comment: Is it this [zig](https://ziglang.org/)?

Comment: Yes @Scheff, My edit to the tag wiki is awaiting review

Comment: @KamiKaze Yes, I've found this! The "constexpr" like functions are optimized! Thanks guys.

Comment: Zig now supports this example and I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When this question was asked, translate-c did not yet support functions with unspecified parameters. This was visible by using `--verbose-cimport`:

```
test.c:1:5: warning: unsupported type: 'FunctionNoProto'
test.c:1:5: warning: unable to resolve prototype of function 'main'
```

In C, if you leave the parameters empty, it's not actually zero parameters, it's unspecified. You have to use `void` to mean "no parameters".

So that's why the second example worked - because the parameter list was not empty.

However as of [e280dce3](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/commit/e280dce30f7a5d5cf6fc2001bac5e3918f8b5a39), Zig supports translating C functions with unspecified parameters, and the example from the question turns into this Zig code:

```
pub export fn main() c_int {
    return 1;
}
```